# EF Core retornar objeto ya existente al insertar objeto principal

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Estoy empezando un poco con EF Core y tengo una duda.

Tengo la tipica API de Pets de Swagger y estoy haciendo unos insert.
De momento me los hace correcto, pero yo quiero que la *navegacion Category* de la *clase principal Pet* se cree nueva solo si no existe en la base de datos.

No veo como hacerlo.He probado a buscar la categoria yo y si existe cambiarla, pero cuando le doy a SaveChangesAsync() sige intentando crearla.

¿Puede que en vez de  tener la propiedad Category de la clase Category hacer una propiedad CategoryId??

Me ayudais? Gracias!

```
//MODELOS
public partial class Pet : IEquatable<Pet>
    {
        [DataMember(Name="id", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="category", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataMember(Name="name", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Category : IEquatable<Category>
    {
        [DataMember(Name="id", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="name", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

```
//DBContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Name}).IsUnique();

            });            

            modelBuilder.Entity<Pet>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsUnicode(false);               

                entity
                .HasOne<Category>(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany();

                entity.Navigation(e => e.Category).AutoInclude();

            });
}
```

```
//CONTROLADOR
 public async Task<ActionResult<Pet>> PostPet(Pet pet)
        {
            _context.Pets.Add(pet);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPet", new { id = pet.Id }, pet);
        }
```

Comment: Hola, ponga un punto de ruptura en la primera línea de código para poder ver el objeto `pet` de todos modos no creo que le esté duplicando datos xq tiene el `Name` de `Category` cómo único

Comment: Mi problema no es si se duplica o no. Lo que quiero es que en vez de insertar un nuevo registo en categories que ya existe me devuelva el id del que ya esta, por que si no imaginate si alguien mete como categoria de mascota el nombre "domestico" tendria muchisimas ocurrencias.Efectivamente eso haria que el nombre fuese unico, pero con el unique index no me funciona solo hace que falle en caso de insertar algo que existe

Comment: Qué tiene de malo hacer un `var categoria = _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(cat => cat.Name == nombreCategoriaQueQuieresChecar);`? Si `categoria` es `null`, entonces, tienes que crearla porque no existe, si categoria **no** es `null`, entonces haces `var categoriaId = categoria.Id;` para obtener el Id.

Comment: al final hice algo parecido pero con el id, si existe lo guardo en categoriaId (que en el codigo que puse no estaba todavia) y categoria lo pongo a null. si no existe con dejarlo como esta me lo crea. Yo pense que EF Coree tendria algo para esta situacion sin yo tener que hacer nada manual